# How do I specify the type of a prop to refer to the type of another prop?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm not entirely sure how to ask this question, or what lingo to use, so I'm going to give this my best shot.

I want to write a component that works on an array of items, and will call a function render each item. I *don't* want to specify the type of the item, or the arguments to the render function, but I *do* want to make sure they match.  Here's an example of what I'd like to do:

```
type MyComponentProps<ItemType = any> = {
    items: ItemType[];
    renderItem: (item: ItemType, index: number) => React.ReactElement;
};

const MyComponent = ({ items, renderItem }: MyComponentProps) => {
    return <div>{items.map((item, index) => renderItem(item, index))}</div>;
};
```

Taking this example component, I'd like to be able to use it like this:

```
const App = () => {
    const items: string[] = ['foo', 'bar'];
    const renderItem = (item: string, index: number) => <div>{item}</div>;

    // This should be happy, and work fine
    return <MyComponent items={items} renderItem={renderItem} />;
}
```

However, I'd like this to fail:

```
const App = () => {
    const items: number[] = [1, 2];
    const renderItem = (item: string, index: number) => <div>{item}</div>;

    // This should generate a type error
    return <MyComponent items={items} renderItem={renderItem} />;
}
```

Should I be able to do something like this?  I bet there is a way to make `MyComponent` generic, and then make a specific instance of that component where I need it for each `ItemType` I want to pass in.  But I also think there might be a way to make the `renderItem` type refer to the `items` type somehow to make sure they all line up.

Comment: You'd have to do something like `<MyComponent<number> items={items} renderItem={renderItem} />` and pass that type back along the chain; right now `ItemType = any` basically means the generic type is pointless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were really close. All you need to do is to add a generic type to the `MyComponent` function.

```
type MyComponentProps<ItemType> = {
    items: ItemType[];
    renderItem: (item: ItemType, index: number) => React.ReactElement;
};

const MyComponent = <T,>({ items, renderItem }: MyComponentProps<T>) => {
    return <div>{items.map((item, index) => renderItem(item, index))}</div>;
};
```

`T` will be inferred as the type passed for `items`. If this does not match with `item` in the function parameters, an error is shown.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=10&ssc=3&pln=3&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wChSYBPMJOAWUoGFdIA7JVmABRzAGcAPAEkYSEABVqSAHxwAvHADepOKrjBRIPgC44IsZJoBtALoBuFWqKsAJkij6QugBQaxux4aQAadbaQAHrqsAK4gAEb2AJTyssjoMAB08RgAogA2YhwwFgC%20FqRoEKx88AzM4MXZ8nAC4t7Szorqmny%201nYOmnC5uuUsVZw8EPx10jFysspqcEQwIVCstTbAAG7Sim5aiSAoYM6umr7A-gETsh32jodix6dRUbkCAPQr63kFRSXwAIJgYDVnOclJZVF9Si0xHwAIy6UpQE4Ac1MNSMAHJMBAIGjfGjwigoGjzKC4OD4JcumJoYCtnCYAjWIi7nYgnBQhForFlmsNlsnq8eQUZmTIVoAEzBMKRKAohRGaG%20MXE4XFCEUxximmaOkMpl%20FmSjlQYECN68zT8s1CtTPZ5wcQAC2AfDgfAdEBC6RscEicAdezAlF8KFscAA7tAANZwTAnJAkuYLJYCaQk1QCfqVdicUV8OSbVrQ3KzDidRz59WaItwZ6pmbpzNsapbPMFqFi4uVsQV0tXTQdmt1tQvaR5IA)

Comment: When I run this I see `T` inferred based on `item` in `renderItem`, and it says _`items`_ is wrong: https://tsplay.dev/Na2npm.

Comment: Wow! This is great.  I have never seen the `<T,>` syntax before, so this is a great thing to learn.

Comment: @jonrsharpe while I agree, I want to have the type derived from the `items` prop, I think just making the compiler complain is good enough.  Maybe there's a better solution out there? IDK, but this seems to work

Comment: @peterw I'm not sure it matters which way around, if you're going to insist on inference, as long as the compiler tells you they're not compatible. My point was that this answer is backwards per the linked playgrounds - `T` is inferred based on `renderItem`, not `items`.

Answer (score 1):

You're so close @peterw! Here's all you had to change:

```js
/* notice that we're using 'extends' instead of '=' here */
type MyComponentProps<ItemType extends any> = { 
  items: ItemType[]
  renderItem: (item: ItemType, index: number) => React.ReactElement
}

/* notice that we're making this generic */
const MyComponent = <ItemType extends any>({
  items,
  renderItem,
}: MyComponentProps<ItemType>) => {
  return <div>{items.map((item, index) => renderItem(item, index))}</div>
}

const App1 = () => {
  const items: string[] = ['foo', 'bar']
  const renderItem = (item: string) => <div>{item}</div>

  return <MyComponent items={items} renderItem={renderItem} /> // no errors here
}

const App2 = () => {
  const items: number[] = [1, 2]
  const renderItem = (item: string) => <div>{item}</div>

  return <MyComponent items={items} renderItem={renderItem} /> // Error: Type 'number[]' is not assignable to type 'string[]'.

}
```